# Logging into our site as part of FaceBook authentication on iOS

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When a user clicks on the login with Facebook button on our website, we call:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxx&
redirect_uri=http://xxxxx.com/Account/FBLogin&scope=email,publish_stream
```

Inside of our FBLogin (string code) method we do two things. First we call:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&
redirect_uri=http://xxxxxx.com/Account/FBLogin&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&code=" + code;
```

Then, if the FaceBook login was successful, we login the user into our site.

What is the equivalent of this workflow in iOS?  We basically want to authenticate the user on our servers as part of the Facebook authentication. So when the Facebook authentication returns successfully, our user is also logged into our system.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Facebook iOS SDK, the SSO (single sign on) workflow is more like the Javascript SDK's workflow because the user is presented with what's similar to the JS SDK's *popup*: either in the form of a UIWebView, Safari Browser, or Facebook app (depending on the user's setup).

> One of the most compelling features of the iOS SDK is Single Sign-On
>   (SSO). SSO lets users sign into your app using their Facebook
>   identity. If they are already signed into the Facebook iOS app on
>   their device, they do not have to type a username and password.
>   Furthermore, you can get permission from users to access their
>   Facebook profile information and social graph.
>
> SSO primarily works by redirecting users to the Facebook app on their
>   devices. Since users are already logged into Facebook, they will not
>   need to enter their username and password to identify themselves. They
>   will see the Auth Dialog with the permissions that your app has asked
>   for, and will be redirected to your mobile app with the appropriate
>   access_token.
>
> Developers should be aware that Facebook SSO will behave slightly
>   differently depending on what is installed on a user's device. This is
>   what happens in certain iOS configurations:
>
> - If the app is running in a version of iOS that supports multitasking,
>     and if the device has the Facebook app of version 3.2.3 or greater
>     installed, the SDK attempts to open the Auth Dialog within the
>     Facebook app. After the user grants or declines, the Facebook app
>     redirects back to the calling app, passing the access token,
>     expiration, and any other parameters the Facebook OAuth server may
>     return.
> - If the app is running in a version of iOS that supports multitasking,
>     but the device doesn't have the Facebook app of version 3.2.3 or
>     greater installed, the SDK will open the Auth Dialog in the Safari
>     mobile browser. After the user grants or revokes the authorization,
>     Safari redirects back to the calling app. Similar to the Facebook app
>     based authorization, this allows multiple apps to share the same
>     Facebook user access_token through the Safari cookie.
> - If the app is running in a version of iOS that does not support
>     multitasking, the SDK uses the old mechanism of popping up an inline
>     UIWebView, prompting the user to log in to Facebook and grant access.
>     The FBSessionDelegate is a callback interface that your app should
>     implement: The delegate methods will be invoked when the app
>     successful logs in or logs out. Read the iOS SDK documentation for
>     more details on this delegate.

... when the user finishes either signing in or not signing in and returns to your app from the "popup", your app has to decide what to do based on whether or not the user logged in/authorized the app (and a valid access token received).

Please read this for more info: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso